# Comparing two iterators and checking which elements were added, removed or the same between the two

Tags: java, iterator

I'm writing some code that takes in two iterators based on two huge lists of data. For simplicity you can imagine that both are lists of numbers. The same number can exist in either list one or two or in both.

What it should do is go over both of the lists and while it's doing that, determine which of the encountered items exist in both lists, which ones exist only in list one and which ones only exist in list two.

I could create collections containing all of the values of the first one and the second one and use them to do the diff but the code will be used for comparing really large datasets with each other (millions of records). Loading the 2 sets in memory is not an option, it has to be in a "streaming fashion".

I can sort the 2 lists before processing them so you can assume they will be ordered.

This is the best I can come up with but it's getting stuck in an endless loop in some cases:

```
public class ChangeScanner {

    public static <T> void compareEntriesOfTwoStreams(Iterator<T> sourceOne,
                                                      Iterator<T> sourceTwo,
                                                      Comparator<T> comparator) {
        T valueInOne = sourceOne.next();
        T valueInTwo = sourceTwo.next();

        while (sourceOne.hasNext() || sourceTwo.hasNext()) {
            if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Present in both list 1 and 2: " + valueInOne);
                valueInOne = getNextValue(valueInOne, sourceOne);
                valueInTwo = getNextValue(valueInTwo, sourceTwo);

            } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) < 0) {

                System.out.println("Present in list 1, Not present in list 2: " + valueInOne);
                valueInOne = getNextValue(valueInOne, sourceOne);

            } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) > 0) {

                System.out.println("Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: " + valueInTwo);
                valueInTwo = getNextValue(valueInTwo, sourceTwo);

            }
        }
    }

    private static <T> T getNextValue(T current, Iterator<T> iterator) {
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            return iterator.next();
        }

        return current;
    }
}
```

And a simple JUnit test that demonstrates it:

```
@Test
public void testIteratorComparingFail() {

    List<String> tableOne = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "14", "15", "16", "17");
    List<String> tableTwo = Lists.newArrayList("8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13");

    ChangeScanner.compareEntriesOfTwoStreams(tableOne.iterator(), tableTwo.iterator(), String::compareTo);
}
```

What I basically do now is:

```
Order everything from small to large before checking.

check 1 and 8 -> 1 is smaller so I know that 1 is not present in list 2. Advance one.
check 2 and 8 -> 2 is smaller so I know that 2 is not present in list 2. Advance one.
...
check 8 and 8 -> it exists in both lists. Advance one and two.
check 9 and 9 -> it exists in both lists. Advance one and two.
check 14 and 10 -> 14 is larger than 10 so I know that 10 is not present in list 1. Two will now loop further to catch up. Advance two.
check 14 and 11 -> 14 is larger than 11 so I know that 11 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
check 14 and 12 -> 14 is larger than 12 so I know that 12 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
check 14 and 13 -> 14 is larger than 13 so I know that 13 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
```

This all works really nice until one of the iterators runs to an end.
In this case it's iterator 2 which is now finished (13 is the last element).

The current logic will get stuck in the last check because it can't advance iterator two anymore but iterator one still has more elements:

```
check 14 and 13 -> 14 is larger than 13 so I know that 13 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
check 14 and 13 -> 14 is larger than 13 so I know that 13 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
check 14 and 13 -> 14 is larger than 13 so I know that 13 is not present in list 1. Advance two.
```

Here is where I can't figure out what to do. I'm pretty sure I have to include some additional logic when either of the iterators has finished.

Two questions:

I have been looking for a third party library that does exactly this because I didn't want to invent this myself. If there is any, please let me know :)

If not I am wondering what checks I can add to handle one of the 2 iterators ending.

Comment: what exactly do you want to get from the function? different elements, number of different elements, a boolean they are not equal?

Comment: In the real code the system.out.printlns are calls to (java 8) functions you can provide to this utility as well. That way you can "hook in" and do anything when any of the three cases (added, removed, or the same) occur. In this example, my aim is to get the correct prints to be executed for every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting challenge because iterators can be consumed only once, and code should not discard value read from the iterator too early.

I can come up only with a recursive solution, but it is better if you could rewrite it with loops

```
static <T> void diff(Iterator<T> lefts, Iterator<T> rights, Comparator<T> comparator,
        Consumer<T> onlyLeft, Consumer<T> equals, Consumer<T> onlyRight) {
    while (lefts.hasNext() && rights.hasNext()) {
        recur(lefts.next(), rights.next(), lefts, rights, comparator, onlyLeft, equals, onlyRight);
    }
    if (!lefts.hasNext()) {
        rights.forEachRemaining(onlyRight);
    }
    if (!rights.hasNext()) {
        lefts.forEachRemaining(onlyLeft);
    }
}

static <T> void recur(T left, T right, Iterator<T> lefts, Iterator<T> rights,
        Comparator<T> comparator, Consumer<T> onlyLeft, Consumer<T> equals,
        Consumer<T> onlyRight) {
    if (comparator.compare(left, right) == 0) {
        equals.accept(left);
    } else if (comparator.compare(left, right) < 0) {
        onlyLeft.accept(left);
        if (lefts.hasNext()) {
            recur(lefts.next(), right, lefts, rights, comparator, onlyLeft, equals, onlyRight);
        } else {
            onlyRight.accept(right);
        }
    } else {
        onlyRight.accept(right);
        if (rights.hasNext()) {
            recur(left, rights.next(), lefts, rights, comparator, onlyLeft, equals, onlyRight);
        } else {
            onlyLeft.accept(left);
        }
    }
}
```

The simple test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> tableOne = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    List<String> tableTwo = Lists.newArrayList("2", "2", "5", "7", "8");

    diff(tableOne.iterator(), tableTwo.iterator(), String::compareTo,
            left -> System.out.println("Left " + left),
            both -> System.out.println("Both " + both),
            right -> System.out.println("Right " + right));

}
```

Outputs

```
Left 1
Both 2
Right 2
Left 3
Left 4
Both 5
Left 6
Right 7
Right 8
```

Answer (score 1):

> We can write function using below pseudo taking care of corner cases

```
 while list1 and list2 has element
  if(list1.next < list2.next)
      keep advancing list1 these are in list1 and not in list2
  else if(list1.next > list2.next)
     keep advancing list2 these are in list2 and not in list1
  else if(list1.next == list2.next)
     advance both list1 and list2  these are common in both list

 while(list1.hasNext)   
   all remaining are only in list1 

 while(list2.hasNext)   
   all remaining are only in list2
```

> WORKING CODE

```
public static <T> void compareEntriesOfTwoStreams(Iterator<T> sourceOne, Iterator<T> sourceTwo,
        Comparator<T> comparator) {
    T valueInOne = sourceOne!=null ? sourceOne.hasNext() ? sourceOne.next() : null:null;
    T valueInTwo = sourceTwo!=null ? sourceTwo.hasNext() ? sourceTwo.next() : null:null;  
    while (valueInOne != null && valueInTwo != null) {

        if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) > 0) {
            // advance sourcetwo
            while (valueInTwo != null && comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) > 0) {
                System.out.println("Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: " + valueInTwo);
                valueInTwo = sourceTwo.hasNext() ? sourceTwo.next() : null;
            }

        } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) < 0) {
            // advance sourceone 
            while (valueInOne != null && comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) < 0) {
                // this will advance
                System.out.println("Not present in list 2, Present in list 1: " + valueInOne);
                valueInOne = sourceOne.hasNext() ? sourceOne.next() : null;
            }

        } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) ==0) {
            System.out.println("present in both list:" + valueInOne);
            valueInTwo = sourceTwo.hasNext() ? sourceTwo.next() : null;
            valueInOne = sourceOne.hasNext() ? sourceOne.next() : null;
            // present in both list if one of list is ended
        }

    }

    while (valueInOne != null) {
        // all these are only in list1
        System.out.println("Not present in list 2, Present in list 1: " + valueInOne);
        valueInOne = sourceOne.hasNext() ? sourceOne.next() : null;
    }

    while (valueInTwo != null) {
        // these are only in list2
        System.out.println("Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: " + valueInTwo);
        valueInTwo = sourceTwo.hasNext() ? sourceTwo.next() : null;
    }
}
```

**sample run**

```
compareEntriesOfTwoStreams(Stream.of(1,2,3,10).iterator(), Stream.of(3,4,10,12).iterator(), Integer::compare);
```

**output**

```
Not present in list 2, Present in list 1: 1
Not present in list 2, Present in list 1: 2
present in both list                    : 3
Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: 4
present in both list                    : 10
Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines inside the while loop solved this.

```
        if(!sourceOne.hasNext())
          {
            sourceTwo.next();
          }
        if(!sourceTwo.hasNext())
          {
            sourceOne.next();
          }
```

Complete Code:

```
 public static <T> void compareEntriesOfTwoStreams(Iterator<T> sourceOne,
                                                  Iterator<T> sourceTwo,
                                                  Comparator<T> comparator) {
    T valueInOne = sourceOne.next();
    T valueInTwo = sourceTwo.next();

    while (sourceOne.hasNext() || sourceTwo.hasNext()) {

        if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Present in both list 1 and 2: " + valueInOne);
            valueInOne = getNextValue(valueInOne, sourceOne);
            valueInTwo = getNextValue(valueInTwo, sourceTwo);

        } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) < 0) {

            System.out.println("Present in list 1, Not present in list 2: " + valueInOne);
            valueInOne = getNextValue(valueInOne, sourceOne);

        } else if (comparator.compare(valueInOne, valueInTwo) > 0) {

            System.out.println("Not present in list 1, Present in list 2: " + valueInTwo);
            valueInTwo = getNextValue(valueInTwo, sourceTwo);

        }
        if(!sourceOne.hasNext())
        {
            sourceTwo.next();
        }
        if(!sourceTwo.hasNext())
        {
            sourceOne.next();
        }

    }
}

private static <T> T getNextValue(T current, Iterator<T> iterator) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return iterator.next();
    }

    return current;
}
```